# Ajaxly login/signup in bootstrap modal

Tags: theming, forms, users, 8, ajax

This is sample modal sample of boostrap modal

```
<div id="signin" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and this is a line trigger modal in `header.html.twig`,

```
 <li><a type="button" class="btn btn-lg navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup"> {{ 'SIGNUP'|t }}</a></li>
```

**goal:** open login form in bootsrap modal.

I find the name of file I can customize user-login block , it's `block--userlogin.html.twig`
then my markup

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="signin" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" action="{{ path( "user.login" ) }}"   role="form" name="loginform">
                    {% if error %}
                        <div class="warning">
                            <h3>{{ "Could not login" }}</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>{{ "A valid username and password is required to login." }}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" value="{{username }}"   name="_username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="{{ "username or email :"|t}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" ame="_password" placeholder="{{ "Password"|t }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{ "Sign In"|t }}</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**but** with this action `action="{{ path( "user.login" ) }}"` it redirect me to `user/login` page. 
**I want to know how can I login/signup usuer ajaxly in modal without redirect to user/login page?**

Comment: Only +50? I will be building an ajax login/signup module soon for my D8 project.

Comment: @NoSssweat I'm not rich :D. 50 is good ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two questions:

**1.) goal: open login form in bootsrap modal.**

In your code by redirecting to a new path the page will reload, and not display a modal login.

But you don't need a new path, your form is already there. It is in the block content and you should be able to place `{{ content }}` in the bootstrap modal dialog like this.

**block--userlogin.html.twig:**

```
<div id="signin" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ content }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**2.) ajaxifing the login (not reloading *after* submit)**

For this there is some work to do, you can see this in the D7 module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_register

For D8 you need to code something similar.

Comment: Thank you for for attention, but  I need  ajax login/singup more

Comment: can you provide ajax login syntax and snippets?

Comment: At the moment only D7 code exists: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ajax_register/tree/ajax_register.module

Comment: Finally I did what I need with custom code :(, this is not solution for what I asked

Comment: @zhilevan where you able to do ajax form validation? Ex: Wrong password message appears inside your modal.

Comment: @NoSssweat finally I did what I want, thanks for your attention, yes I did it in modal. in modal if user not authorized I show boostrap danger message to him.

Comment: @zhilevan ok cool, I am putting the finishing touches to my module.

Comment: @NoSssweat well done, tnx.

Comment: @zhilevan Why not post your solution/approach as and answer here, for other's looking for this exact same thing and landing here from Google? Like me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // You will most likely want to show and render the form for anonymous users.
  $variables['login_form'] = FALSE;
  if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->id()) {
    $form = Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class) ; 
    $render = Drupal::service('renderer');
    $variables['login_form'] = $render->renderPlain($form);
  }
}
```

Put `{{ login_form }}` in your twig file

Comment: what is this  ? you get rendered login form and pass it by variable to page.
No, what I ask about is , how can ajaxly login in boostrap modal

Comment: i am not very good in drupal 8, but logic is you need to do every thing at your own, means from model box containing login form, then hit an ajax request on your custom url made by hook menu and at hook menu callback function  you need to login finalize and return response. after getting response in ajax just reload the DOM. you are now logged in