# Opening a nested paragraph in a modal window

Tags: paragraphs

I have a paragraph (image with some fields) inside a parent paragraph.

Inside the template of the parent paragraph I'd like to open the nested paragraph via link () in a modal window.

How can I access the nested paragraph in the template of the parent paragraph as a link?

Comment: A paragraph can not have a link. This is the point of paragraphs, they have a mandatory parent entity, they are no standalone entites with links.

Comment: Yes, so the easiest way would be to design the paragraph type as a jQuery or Bootstrap modal window. That's the main use case of the Paragraphs module, adding styles and javascript to paragraph types.

Comment: I want to design the paragraph as a modal window. But how can I access it in the parent paragraph template?

Comment: The modal paragraph type would render itself as a link that opens the hidden modal content. See for example https://www.jquerymodal.com

Comment: The modal window itself is not my problem. I need to know how to access the referenced paragraphs content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the host paragraph when a paragraph is referenced in another paragraph?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232932/how-do-i-get-the-host-paragraph-when-a-paragraph-is-referenced-in-another-paragr)

Answer (score 0):

The most generic solution would be a layout paragraph type designed to display a hidden modal window. A layout paragraph type usually contains only one field, a paragraph reference field to add more nested paragraphs. There is no need to reference nested or parent paragraphs, paragraphs render recursively.

You can also make a modal version of the image paragraph type which puts `{{ content }}`, containing the image field and other fields, in a modal window body. See for example [Ajaxly login/signup in bootstrap modal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204057/ajaxly-login-signup-in-bootstrap-modal/206622#206622)

Comment: My problem is, that I don't know how to make the modal version of the image paragraph.

Comment: I've linked an answer moving the content of a block in a modal window. This works the same for a paragraph template.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I don't know how to call the modal version of the paragraph. I can build a modal specific template for the modal version of the image. But how should the link to the paragraph with the specific view mode look like?

Comment: `paragraph--paragraph-type--view-mode.html.twig`

Comment: This is the filename of the template. OK. I don't know how I access (in link) the referenced paragraph in parent paragraphs template.

In

paragraph--parent--full.html.twig: <a href="{{ PARAGRAPH_REFERENCED_VIEW-MODE }}>link text</a>

the paragraph_referenced_view-mode I need.

Comment: We've discussed this already in the first comments. Paragraphs don't have routes so no Drupal links. You edit and render them inline (if you want in a hidden modal window).